# python - Get input argument's name of function

Tags: python, function, arguments

How can I get name of input argument in function?

Here is example

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
def test(x):
    print(?)

test(b)
```

and result should be

```
b
```

I think this is easy problem...? But not to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that multiple variables can have the same value, the below function returns a list of all the variable names that holds the value passed in as argument:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
def test(x):
    print([k for k, v in globals().items() if v == x])

test(b)
```

Output:

```
['b']
```

---

Of course, you can always return after the first occurrence of a match:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
def test(x):
    for k, v in globals().items():
        if v == x:
            return print(k)

test(b)
```

Output:

```
b
```